# Scrollable div after fixed top div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to build a mobile html page with a fixed Header and a Scrollable List right after. The header contains a logo that has a fuild size regarding the dimensions of the container.

The problem is that the first element of the list gets under the header and I don't have a height defined because the header has a fluid height.

The HTML:

```
<header>
    <figure>
        <img src="images/logo.png" />
    </figure>
</header>

<main>
    <ul id="shops-list">
        <li>Company #1</li>
        <li>Company #2</li>
    </ul>
</main>
```

THE CSS:

```
// global definition for fluid images
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}

header figure {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

header figure img {
    max-width: 100px;
}

main { 
    ???
}
```

EDIT:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q42yaaz4/2/

Comment: add a fiddle/codepen to reproduce the issue so we can look into a CSS-only solution

Comment: Hi Luca, I have edited the question with the Fiddle code reproducing the issue.

Comment: Hey, I've updated my answer to fix a problem, so kindly check it out.

Comment: @Patrick consider selecting answer as best answer if you find any, otherwise provide your persisting problem in detail..

Comment: @RohitKumar Hi, So sorry for the delay, I have checked your answer as correct because it's nice, clean and simple and the best for me. Thank you very much for your help ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use pure JS to do that since your `header` `height` is not fixed.
It will be better if you add an `id` to your `header` and `main`. Suppose you've added that.

```
var h = document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("main").style.marginTop = h+"px";
```

You can use this JS to create a `margin-top` on `main` which is equal to the visible `height` of the `header`

**UPDATE**

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q42yaaz4/3/), I have added the following code so to accompany the `margin-top` of `main` ***on resize of window***, because you are designing a fluid layout.

```
var el = document.getElementById("header");
document.getElementById("main").style.marginTop = el.offsetHeight+"px";

window.onresize = function() {
document.getElementById("main").style.marginTop = el.offsetHeight+"px";
};
```

try resizing the fiddle window and see the `margin-top` is updated instantly so that `main` always appear just below `header`

Comment: Nice. I couldn't have answered it better. :)

Comment: I don't have any idea about pure CSS solution right now.

Comment: the only thing I could imagine would be another header with the same content (or at least alsways the same height) placed relatively before the list. But I think the JS solution is more elegant